# Unable to see div inside canvas

Tags: html, css

I am working on the following code. Why am I not able to see the `dot` class in the Canvas?

```css
canvas {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: white;
  position: relative
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 30px;
}
.dot {
  background: #eee;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="map">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="dot">
    </div>
  </div>
</canvas>
```

Comment: The content of the canvas is used as alternate content for browsers that can't draw the canvas.

Comment: `<canvas>` element is used to draw graphics, on the fly, via JavaScript. It won't take html tags inside.

Comment: also, if you want to draw html inside a canvas (captcha  for example) you could take a look at this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp:

> The HTML `<canvas>` element is used to draw graphics, on the fly, via
>   JavaScript.

Any html inside the `<canvas>` element is treated as alternative content to be displayed in browsers not supporting `<canvas>`.